# Elastic Beanstalk Rails deploy mystery initialize error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy an existing heroku app to EC2 using Beanstalk.

So far I have all the Environment variables moved over and the database setup.. etc.  It seems to work and deploy correct except for Puma.

The `puma.log` file has the following in it over and over;

```
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/pathname.rb:397:in `initialize': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/pathname.rb:397:in `new'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/pathname.rb:397:in `join'
    from /var/app/current/config/initializers/cloudfront-signer.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cloudfront-signer-2.2.0/lib/cloudfront-signer.rb:108:in `configure'
    from /var/app/current/config/initializers/cloudfront-signer.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:420:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:419:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:413:in `call'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:413:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
    from /var/app/current/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from config.ru:3:in `require'
    from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from config.ru:in `new'
    from config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.2/lib/puma/configuration.rb:102:in `load_rackup'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.2/lib/puma/configuration.rb:69:in `app'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.2/lib/puma/runner.rb:123:in `app'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.2/lib/puma/runner.rb:130:in `start_server'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.2/lib/puma/cluster.rb:213:in `worker'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.2/lib/puma/cluster.rb:109:in `block (2 levels) in spawn_workers'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.2/lib/puma/cluster.rb:109:in `fork'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.2/lib/puma/cluster.rb:109:in `block in spawn_workers'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.2/lib/puma/cluster.rb:105:in `times'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.2/lib/puma/cluster.rb:105:in `spawn_workers'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.2/lib/puma/cluster.rb:157:in `check_workers'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.2/lib/puma/cluster.rb:421:in `run'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.2/lib/puma/cli.rb:216:in `run'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.2/bin/puma:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/puma:23:in `load'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/puma:23:in `<main>'
```

I have no clue what this is or why its happening and am at a complete loss..

Line 5 of `config/environment` is `Rails.application.initialize!`

Line 3 of `config.ru` is `run Rails.application`

So does this mean that `Rails.application` hasn't been defined?  I'm a tad confused.

Again this app works perfectly on Heroku.

Suggestions?

Comment: Additionally, I created a `hello world` rails application that I have successfully deployed to EB using my exact same approach.  It worked fine.

Comment: More information is neccessary, but I'd look at all of your configuration files to make sure you're not missing a required property somewhere. Nil into string conversion means that it's attempting to get something but isnt. If it works on Heroku, odds are it was something they provided behind the scenes that you are lacking for beanstalk.